# CentOS: How to create a default route after server starts

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking

I'm using CentOS 6.7 on Proxmox KVM.

Now I would like to get my network-connection working.

This is my config:

[image]

Now I have to perform

```
ip route add 89.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0
```

and

```
ip route add default via 89.xxx.xxx.1
```

to get a connection.

Well, I would like to do that automatically, so I created a script like that:

[image]
This is my ifconfig-output:

[image]

This is my routing-table:

[image]

Comment: The configuration shown should be sufficient. Please show your existing routing table after bringing up the interface.

Comment: Hello, I added the routing table after rebooting the system.

Comment: It doesn't appear that your interface came up properly. Check your system logs for errors.

Comment: Since it looks like `eth0` didn't come up right, does the `HWADDR` line match the actual MAC for the device?

Comment: I did not find anything in my logs :-( 

I added all information (ifconfig-output, routing-table, interface-configuration, routing-configuration) to the question. There should be no typo with HWADDR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had the same issue on a server. CentOS didnt add the route automaticly because the gateway is not in the same subnetmask (i guessed).

You need to add a persistent/static route.
CentOS documentation can be found here: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html

Try the following for your route-eth0 file:

```
89.163.148.1 dev eth0
default via 89.163.148.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: Hi,

I tried to. I corrected my question and added my configuration of a persistent route.

Comment: Editted the post, does it work now?